# Angular upgrade from 8 to 9, Can't resolve all parameters for any injectable

Tags: dependency-injection, angular9, ngxs

I recently upgrade form Angular 8 to Angular 9 and it appears that nothing can be dependency injected.

I've commented out so much code in my project to something as basic as the following:

```
// configuration.state.ts
@State<ConfigurationStateModel>({
  name: 'ConfigurationStateModel',
  defaults: defaultConfiguration,
})
export class ConfigurationState {

  constructor(
    //private configurationService: ConfigurationService,
    private configurationService: HeroService,
  ) { }

  // .. irrelevant code

}
```

```
//hero.service.ts
// generated by ng g s heroservice
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Errors with

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ConfigurationState: (?).
>
> at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.js:17311)
>
> at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.js:17295)
>
> at providerToFactory (core.js:17363)
>
> at providerToRecord (core.js:17345)
>
> at R3Injector.processProvider (core.js:17161)
>
> at core.js:17122
>
> at core.js:1400
>
> at Array.forEach ()
>
> at deepForEach (core.js:1400)
>
> at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.js:17118)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently with NGXS, all States must be now decorated with the `@Injectable()`.

This does **not** work:

```
@Injectable()
@State<ConfigurationStateModel>({
  name: 'ConfigurationStateModel',
  defaults: defaultConfiguration,
})
export class ConfigurationState {
```

but adding it after `@State` does:

```
@State<ConfigurationStateModel>({
  name: 'ConfigurationStateModel',
  defaults: defaultConfiguration,
})
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationState {
```